# Maximum Intersection of points between 2 lines and 2 circles

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations

**My approach**

For maximum intersection points , I would want that there should be maximum intersections between lines, circles , and the combinations of lines and circles

**Case 1:** Maximum intersection points between 2 lines = 2c2 * 1 (every pair of line gives maximum of 1 intersection point)

**Case 2:** Maximum intersection points between 2 circles = 2c2 * 2 (a pair of circles will give 2 maximum intersection of points)

**Case 3:** Maximum intersection between lines and circles = (2c1 * 2c1) * 2   (A pair of line and circle will intersect at max 2 points)

giving me my final answer as = 1 * 2 * 8 = 16 points

but while drawing out and inspecting , I am getting 11 points of intersection, can someone guide me where I am going wrong

[image]

Comment: Why are you multiplying the number of points obtained in the three cases? Suppose you have $5$ red boxes and $7$ blue boxes. When asked the total number of boxes with you, will you say you have $5*7=35$ boxes or $5+7=12$ boxes?

Comment: Yeah sorry , I was watching a video where the person was explaining the solution for this problem, I got carried away by his wrong explanation , thanks for pointing it out with nicely framed example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following intersections between [c]ircle and [l]ine:
$$1\cdot ll + 2\cdot2\cdot lc + 1\cdot cc = 1 + 8 + 2 = 11$$

So the $1\cdot 2 \cdot 8$ is a thinko.